# Why is my Threaded Thrift calls slow?

Tags: c++, thrift

My thrift definition is something like this:

```
list<i32> getValues()
```

Implemented it in C++.

Server.cpp has the following piece of code:

.....

```
std::vector<int32_t> store;

  TransferServiceHandler() {
    for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++)
      store.push_back(i);
  }

  void getValues(std::vector<int32_t> & _return) {
    // Your implementation goes here

    _return = store;

  }
```

.....

Client.cpp has a simple loop in which it calls the getValues():

```
for(int k=0;k<10;k++){

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ds_spec);
  int64_t dstarted = ds_spec.tv_sec * 1000 + (ds_spec.tv_nsec / 1.0e6);

  std::vector<int32_t> values;
  client.getValues(values);


  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &de_spec);
  int64_t dended = de_spec.tv_sec * 1000 + (de_spec.tv_nsec / 1.0e6);

  std::cout << "Values size :" << values.size() << " in " << (dended - dstarted) << " ms\n";

}
```

Connections are initialized and closed outside the loop.

Usually few hundred thousand entries are returned by this call.

When there is no data (when the lists are empty) i can see the call happening in 1ms-2ms, when i vary data there's a unpredictable delay in the transfer. Both the client and server are running on the same machine (equipped with 10Gb/s Ethernet, 8 cores and 30 GB of memory).

How do you normally debug a situation like this? I don't think the issue is with the network since its a 10 Gigs machine and size of the data is hardly few MBs.

[image]

I ran a benchmark with various data size and you can see the delay isn't stable for each call.

Comment: You don't show any code, you don't tell us what your program is doing, what you are measuring, so how do you believe shall we help you?

Comment: Oh thanks for the feedback, I have edited the question and added a sample codebase which can reproduce the delay issue.

Comment: Please post relevant code here, do not link somewhere else and let the link become invalid over time.

Comment: You need to do a network trace, maybe it is a TCP issue (traffic not at maximum speed from beginning on). Also: maybe what you are seeing is that establishing the connection takes some amount of time and that you are not only measuring transfer but establishing the connection plus transfer (thus the better data rate when transfering more); Keep in mind that 5-100 MB is not very much traffic.

Comment: BTW, you may reserve memory for `std::vector<int32_t> store;` to avoid reallocation.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I have edited the question, now it makes more sense.
@WernerHenze I have posted the relevant code here now, also the connection creation is happening only one time in the client side (outside the loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made significant improvement in the performance after transferring the data as binary rather than vector.

On the thrift definition file, changed the list to binary.

Here's the new benchmark on the same amount of data:

[image]

Comment: Is this a complete solution for your problem?

Comment: As of now yes, I couldn't come up with anything better.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I fully understand the interaction between client and server, however your `getValue` method could be improved by using move semantics (C++11), therefore you could move the `store` vector rather then making a copy (memory operations are quite expensive) as follows:

```
  void getValues(std::vector<int32_t> & _return) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    _return = std::move(store);
  }
```

Note that this works fine as long as content of `store` (which now has been moved into _return) does not need to persist beyond the call to `getValue`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are loosing resolution here:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ds_spec);
  int64_t dstarted = ds_spec.tv_sec * 1000 + (ds_spec.tv_nsec / 1.0e6);
```

Which goes against the reason for using `clock_gettime()` to begin with;
[Here](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/22/profiling-code-using-clock_gettime/) is a link on how to profile code using clock_gettime(); hopefully it will solve your problem.

I'm pointing to resolution because this can be a good cause for unexpected profiling results.

Comment: that doesn't help mate, The issue is with thrift serializing and de-serializing the data.  See my own answer, the performance just kicked off when I transferred binary (byteBuffer).